# Apache reverse proxy 302 redirect browsers directly takes to the redirected URL

Tags: redirect, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, glassfish

I have setup a reverse proxy through glassfish server via apache mod_proxy.

my concern is when there is a 302 redirect happens then after that every time i access that url which invoked 302 redirect all the browsers directly takes me to that redirected url.

Please see my apache config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName proxy
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    ProxyPass / http://server:port/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse / http://server:port/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://proxy/

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a global option setup as `ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"`, this was causing the issue.

I put `ExpiresDefault "now"` in my virtual host setting to resolve my problem.